# performance difference between strrev() and array_reverse()

Tags: php, binary, decimal

is there any kind of performance difference between these two?

```
$bin = 1000 //8 in decimal

$bin_a = strrev($bin);
$bin_a = str_split($bin_a);
```

or

```
$bin_b = str_split($bin);
$bin_b = array_reverse($bin_b);
```

or are there any function to convert string to array and reverse at the same time?
I want to manually convert binary to decimal without native php function,
or any simpler way to do this?

Comment: "is there any performance difference" - why didn't you just *try* it yourself?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I don't know how to test it out :/

Comment: @yivi yeah thanks! but what did you mean I'm doing it wrong for optimisation?

Comment: That the performance difference is likely to be too small to be worth the trouble.

Comment: @yivi I see, thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a meaningful difference.
And not diffifcult to test out. You should be able to write a test like this without any trouble whatsoever.

```
<?php

$start_a = microtime(true);
$bin     = "1000"; //8 in decimal

for ($n = 0; $n < 1000000; $n++) {

    $bin_a = strrev($bin);
    $bin_a = str_split($bin_a);
}

$end_a = microtime(true);

echo "Took ", $end_a - $start_a, " seconds \n";

$start_b = microtime(true);


for ($n = 0; $n < 1000000; $n++) {

    $bin_b = str_split($bin);
    $bin_b = array_reverse($bin_b);
}


$end_b = microtime(true);

echo "Took ", $end_b - $start_b, " seconds \n";
```

Output, for a million repetitions:

> Took 0.26819205284119 seconds
>
> Took 0.39758610725403 seconds

If you are optimizing for this, you are most likely doing it wrong. :)